# What's the formula to select non matching rows by comparing rows in Google Sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets query,
I need to get only **non matching debit rows** by comparing rows say if amount debited (S1 flag - row 1) matches with amount credited (S1 flag - row 3), it needs to be excluded in the result so I only get know the outstanding debit amount which needs to be credited.

| Flag | Transaction | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | Debit | 10 |
| S1 | Debit | 10 |
| S1 | Credit | 10 |
| S2 | Debit | 20 |
| S3 | Debit | 50 |
| S3 | Credit | 50 |

Result needs to be look like  below:

| Flag | Transaction | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | Debit | 10 |
| S2 | Debit | 20 |

My Basic query:

```
=QUERY(K2:M9,"select K, L, M")
```

where K is not null and L = 'Debit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you can turn the source data table above to the result table above with this formula:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    query( 
      { A1:A, if(regexmatch(B1:B, "(?i)Credit"), -C1:C, C1:C), B1:B }, 
      "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
       where Col1 is not null 
       group by Col1", 
      1 
    ), 
    "select Col1, 'Debit', Col2 
     where Col2 <> 0 
     label 'Debit' 'Transaction' ", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

But your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit#gid=789266637) tells that you ultimately need to consider labels `1% Debit`, `2% Debit` and `5% Debit` each separately. You can do that with an array formula that massages the data based on whether a row is Debit or Credit, and aggregate the massaged data with a `query()` that uses a `group by` clause. To weed out rows with a zero result, and create columns for each of `1% Debit`, `2% Debit` and `5% Debit` separately, wrap the `query()` in another `query()` that uses a `pivot` clause, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    query( 
      { A1:A, if(regexmatch(E1:E, "(?i)Credit"), -G1:G, G1:G), E1:E }, 
      "select Col1, sum(Col2), Col3
       where Col1 is not null 
       group by Col1, Col3", 
      1 
    ), 
    "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
     where Col2 <> 0 
     and lower(Col3) contains 'debit' 
     group by Col1 
     pivot Col3", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

To calculate per-flag totals, use this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / ( 1 / sumif( if(column(K7:N29), row(K7:N29)), row(K7:N29), K7:N29 ) ) ) )`

See cells `K6` and `J7` in your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit#gid=789266637).

Note that you can use open-ended references like `A1:A` that will evaluate rows all the way to the bottom of the sheet only when there are no more results or data below the result table. To limit it to some fixed number of rows, use `A1:A500` and so on.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It helps a lot. Works perfectly. But when I tried to display Col2 data which is Debit, and also additional fields like Category, I am getting blank data as result. Please help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. PFB the sheet. 
I need to list 2% Debit, 1% Debit, 5% Debit separately. I will be making an entry after 2% or 1% credit if amount tallies, rows should be excluded.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I will be making an entry as 2% or 1% credit after the amount is credited. After 2% or 1% or 5% credit if amount tallies, rows should be excluded. I need only outstanding 2% or 1% or 5% debit rows which needs to be followed up for credit i.e. after debit, I will be looking a credit when my work is done. I will make entry after credit so that debit row automatically removed from overview.

Comment: Please refer "Copy of Transactions" tab, I31 row table for "2% Debit Status". "Outstanding 2% Debit" should present only when there is value else not row needed. Zeros from M32 to M52 is not needed as we have received the amount.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162guBnG2JBL3uuWuaSN_4xE-NAsGWGwV9ckyKDmmJn4/edit?usp=sharing

Also Flag order needs to be T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11 instead of T1, T10,T11,T2.

Comment: Sure, Thanks a got. Appreciate it.

Comment: @doubleunary Apologies: I'm confused. Is your answer intended to address the OP's question? i.e. offsetting debit/credit transactions. I used your formula (as best as possible given differences in Column letters to OP example data) and it returns the sum of the debit balances (S1 20, S2 20, S3 50) (which is not the OP's expected outcome.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks. Edited the answer to address the X part of this XY problem, and adjusted the solution to the Y part to match the updated sample spreadsheet.